# Firebase rule for firestore append only data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to store a information on firestore and this must be append-only, once is inserted can never be updated.

Can I achive this using only the `firestore rules`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc on **granular operations**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations), a `write` rule can be broken into `create`, `update`, and `delete`.

So you can write a rule along the following lines. It prevents the update or deletion of any doc in the `cities` collection:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // A write rule can be divided into create, update, and delete rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow create: if true;  // Or any other rule with restricted access
      allow update, delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```